# Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 has broken ReportViewer

Tags: .net, asp.net, reportviewer

I've just upgraded from 2008 to 2010 on my dev machine. Running the app gave me an error indicating I needed to change the version number from 9.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 in web.config in the following locations:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```

I assume what has happened is that installed VS2010 has updated the GAC with version 10 of this component.

Problem is, when I publish the app to the live server, the app is broken precisely because it doesn't have version 10.0.0.0.

What is the quickest way to resolve this problem? I'm thinking there must be a way to either:

1) Update the GAC on the server with the latest version of the assembly (but what might that break?)
2) 'Undo' the change to the GAC on my dev machine to use 9.0.0.0 instead.

Or is there another option? Can anyone provide some advice on how to overcome this?

Comment: Eh? Why the downvote? How is this question not relevant? Is it not possible someone else could have the same problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is in reference and using correct files

Reference the file it in your project, and set properties as copy local
this should solve your problem.

ps make sure you select correct version (10/9/8)

Answer (score 0):

Both version 9 and 10 work with Visual Studio 2010, so make sure your project is still referencing version 9.  The only reason you'll get that error when running the app is if you're referencing v10, but still have the v9 config.

Comment: Thanks. On the dev machine, specifying version 9 results in an error though, presumably because this version is no longer in the GAC.

Comment: You can still xcopy deploy the assemblies necessary, though.  I prefer to set Copy Local = true on references so that a published version could just be copied to the server rather than relying on the GAC.